# No analytic continuations of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{z - e^{i \pi \lambda n}}$ beyond unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am working on the following complex analysis problem:

> Let $\lambda$ be irrational and let $\left\{a_n\right\} \subset \mathbf{C}$, $\sum |a_n| < \infty$ and $a_n \neq 0$.  Letting $D = \left\{ z \in \mathbf{C} \colon |z| < 1 \right\}$, define $$ f(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{z - e^{i \pi \lambda n}} \;\;\;\;\; \left( z \in D \right). $$  Show that $f(z)$ is analytic on $D$ and cannot be analytically continued to any larger domain containing $D$.

It is clear that the series absolutely converges uniformly on compact sets, hence $f(z)$ is analytic.  It is also clear that the series diverges for all $z$ on the unit circle $S^1$.

I have been having trouble determining whether $f(z_n)$ diverges if $z_n \to z_0 \in S^1$ (because the convergence of the series is not necessarily uniform on $D$).  If this were generally true, then $f(z)$ couldn't be extended to a continuous function on any larger (connected) domain.  But I am concerned, since the question specifically addresses analytic continuations, that this may not be the right way to go about it.  Perhaps I need to use some complex-analytic-specific theorem (it is kind of an "anti-Abel's theorem" statement).  But I don't know which one.  I am not that comfortable with the theory of analytic continuations.

Thanks for your help.

---

EDIT:  Now that I think about it, why is it so clear that the series diverges on $S^1$?  Since the $a_n$ go to $0$, what if, say, $|a_n| \leq 2^{-n} |z - e^{i \lambda \pi n}|$?

Comment: As written, it's wrong. Taking $\lambda = r\pi$ for $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ would give you an entire meromorphic function. Either the denominator should be $z - e^{i\lambda \pi n}$, or it should read "$\lambda$ not a rational multiple of $\pi$" or equivalent Or maybe "$\lambda$ rational".

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that the sequence $\exp(i\pi \lambda n)$ is dense in $S^1$ for $\pi \lambda$ irrational?

Comment: Yes, this is why the series diverges on $S^1$.  (And @Alex, referring to Daniel's comment, it is for $\lambda$ irrational, not $\pi \lambda$ irrational.)

Comment: And so I'm clear about what I've thought about, just because the formula of the series is not defined on $S^1$ doesn't *a priori* mean that the series cannot extend continuously to points on $S^1$.  (In contrast, Abel's theorem says that if a *power series* converges at a point on $S^1$ and in all of $D$, then the series *does* behave continuously in this way -- for sequences approaching the boundary point within a cone.)

Comment: @Doug: I'm confused about your comment. If $f$ diverges at every single point of $S^1$, then there's no way to extend it analytically. There would be no limits to speak of as you would have a singularity that's an interval and hence there's no analytic continuation. It would suffice to show the derivative of $f$ blows up at every point on the unit circle.

Comment: Here is the statement that I don't agree with: "Since the series diverges on $S^1$, it follows immediately that $f(z)$ has no analytic continuation beyond $D$."  Here is the statement that I do agree with: "If I can show for all $z \in S^1$ that there is a sequence $z_n \to z$ such that $f(z_n)$ diverges, then it follows that $f(z)$ has no analytic continuation."  @Alex, do you agree with me on both accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We expect the unit circle to be the natural boundary of $f$ because the set $\{ e^{i\pi \lambda n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of points where one of the terms of the series has a pole is dense in the unit circle, and "there should not be enough cancellation possible to make such a point regular". The poles of the terms should remain singularities - not poles, of course, since they are not isolated - of $f$, and we expect "pole-like" behaviour of $f$ at $w_k = e^{i\pi \lambda k}$.

It is more or less evident that only the terms with $w_n = e^{i\pi \lambda n}$ close to $w_k$ can have a major influence on the behaviour. More precisely, given $\varepsilon > 0$, the function

$$f_{k,\varepsilon}(z) = \sum_{\substack{n = 0\\\lvert w_n - w_k\rvert \geqslant \varepsilon}}^\infty \frac{a_n}{z - w_n}$$

is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{z : \lvert z\rvert = 1, \lvert z - w_k\rvert \geqslant \varepsilon\}$. The locally uniform convergence of that series on the indicated domain is not difficult to show.

So to prove the singular behaviour of $f$ at $w_k$, it suffices to show that we can choose $\varepsilon > 0$ so that $\lim\limits_{r\to 1} \lvert s_{k,\varepsilon}(r\cdot w_k)\rvert = \infty$, where

$$s_{k,\varepsilon}(z) = \sum_{\substack{n = 0\\ \lvert w_n - w_k \rvert < \varepsilon}}^\infty \frac{a_n}{z-w_n}$$

and $r\in [0,1)$.

By the convergence of $\sum \lvert a_n\rvert$, for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$ there is an $n_k\in \mathbb{N}$ (necessarily $n_k > k$) such that

$$\sum_{n = n_k}^\infty \lvert a_n\rvert < \frac{\lvert a_k\rvert}{2}.\tag{$\ast$}$$

Set $\varepsilon = \min \{ \lvert w_n - w_k\rvert : n < n_k, n \neq k\}$. Since all $w_n$ are distinct, $\varepsilon > 0$, and we have

\begin{align}
\lvert s_{k,\varepsilon}(z)\rvert &\geqslant \frac{\lvert a_k\rvert}{\lvert z - w_k\rvert} - \sum_{\substack{n = n_k\\ \lvert w_n - w_k\rvert < \varepsilon}}^\infty \frac{\lvert a_n\rvert}{\lvert z - w_n\rvert}\\
&\geqslant \frac{\lvert a_k\rvert}{\lvert z - w_k\rvert} - \sum_{n = n_k}^\infty \frac{\lvert a_n\rvert}{\lvert z - w_n\rvert}
\end{align}

for $z\in D$. Now if $z = r\cdot w_k$ for $r\in [0,1)$, then $\lvert z - w_n\rvert \geqslant \lvert z - w_k\rvert$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and therefore

\begin{align}
\lvert s_{k,\varepsilon}(r\cdot w_k)\rvert &\geqslant \frac{\lvert a_k\rvert}{\lvert r\cdot w_k - w_k\rvert} - \sum_{n = n_k}^\infty \frac{\lvert a_n\rvert}{\lvert r\cdot w_k - w_n\rvert}\\
&\geqslant \frac{\lvert a_k\rvert}{\lvert r\cdot w_k - w_k\rvert} - \sum_{n = n_k}^\infty \frac{\lvert a_n\rvert}{\lvert r\cdot w_k - w_k\rvert}\\
&= \frac{1}{1-r}\biggl(\lvert a_k\rvert - \sum_{n = n_k}^\infty \lvert a_n\rvert\biggr)\\
&> \frac{\lvert a_k\rvert}{2(1-r)}.
\end{align}

This shows that $f$ has radial limit $\infty$ at every $w_n$, and therefore there is no open set $V$ with $V\cap \partial D \neq \varnothing$ and $g$ meromorphic on $V$ with $g \lvert_{V\cap D} \equiv f\lvert_{V\cap D}$. For if such a $V$ and $g$ existed and $\zeta \in V\cap \partial D$, then for all small enough $\delta > 0$ we'd have $A(\zeta; 0, \delta) := \{ z : 0 < \lvert z - \zeta\rvert < \delta\} \subset V$ and $g$ would be holomorphic on $A(\zeta; 0, \delta)$. But then the radial limit of $g$ at $w$ would be finite at every $w \in A(\zeta; 0, \delta) \cap \partial D$, so $\{ n : w_n \in A(\zeta; 0, \delta)\} = \varnothing$, but that contradicts the denseness of $\{ w_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ in $\partial D$.

Comment: Thank you for such a satisfying answer.  I found this question on a recent prelim.  I am frustrated that such a tricky question (in my opinion) would appear on a prelim...  I don't suppose you see any quick and dirty "prelim-style answer"?  Perhaps leveraging some theorem.

Comment: Not really. My quick and dirty answer would be that the poles of the terms are dense in the unit circle, and a pole cannot be cancelled by the other terms in the series. If the question "Why?" comes, I'd have to say "Well, let's calculate ...". There probably is some theorem about such situations, but I haven't yet seen it. (Or maybe I have seen and just forgotten.)

Comment: Alright, thanks again.